# Get Facebook app by access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I have a Facebook access token stored in my database which I use to retrieve data from Facebook.
This access token have been registered by one of my apps, but I have no idea which one.

**Is there a way to find out which of my apps owns this token?**

I have tried https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx without success.

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 2500
>      }
>   }

---

*( I am sure this token is still "active" if by active I mean "still able to retrieve data from the Facebook REST API" )*

Comment: Debug the access token https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Can you please compile this comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @WizKid 's comment:

There is a tool on Facebook, that is designed to help identifying the owner of an access token ( and much more, like expiration date or available scopes )

It is accessible under [developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken)